# Object doesn't show in edit mode

Tags: mesh, objects

[image: Mesh in Object Mode]

[image: Mesh in Edit Mode]

I just click tab to go to edit mode and the object disappears. 
There aren't any armatures or anything else of that kind on the mesh. I'm using Blender 2.74 (latest one).

Comment: try pressing ALT->H in edit mode. It's possible that you accidentally pressed H when you where in edit mode and had everything selected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When your in edit mode, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd>. This unhides objects. What happened in your case, was that you accidentally pressed <kbd>H</kbd> (hide) while you where in edit mode with everything selected.